# What does the command "move it out" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have come aross it in the movie *Ful Metal Jacket*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/Go5fmogWmJY). It's at around 10 seconds.

> It should take 10 seconds to negotiate this obstacle. Quickly **move it out**!

Comment: It sounds to me like "Quickly, move it **on**," in other words, "Get on with it."

Comment: Move out from your current position. The "it" is idiomatic but superfluous.

Comment: [You might want to start using the simple past...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "Move out" or in this case "Move it out" has entered English from military language.

It's most literal meaning is the command "Leave this place now!"

It usually follows other orders, so it's more common meaning is "start carrying out my orders now".  But it still implies the order to leave.

For example:

Run round the block. Move out!

This would mean "Go outside and run round the block now!"